# Vim colorscheme similar to Github

Tags: colorscheme

I want to change my **colorscheme** to the one used by **Github for Ruby**.

I searched for one hour with out any luck. Is the color scheme used by Github open source ? or should I write my own colorscheme inspired by Github's?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: There is now a Vim colorscheme based on Github's syntax highlighting as of 2018: [cormacrelf/vim-colors-github](https://github.com/cormacrelf/vim-colors-github)

---

I think the closest available is the well known [endel/vim-github-colorscheme](https://github.com/endel/vim-github-colorscheme), but it may need some tweaks to suit your taste.

Screenshots from the repo:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

---

It seems that GitHub switched from [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) to [Linguist](https://linguist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for syntax highlighting, but it is handled on the server side in both cases. Also check out [Rouge](http://rouge.jneen.net/) used on GitLab.

---

Finally, there is a related question on Stack Overflow: [Using syntax highlight from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246245/using-syntax-highlight-from-github).

Comment: Hey I already knew about the `endel` but it does not do a good job. How can I integrate Linguist into vim colorscheme?

Comment: You could look up the colors used in the GitHub ruby lexer, and develop your own colorscheme, but this can quickly become tedious. I'll update my answer if I find a lead.